# Error of different tensors sizes, padding is not the solution

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, padding

In pytorch, I'm trying to run the following code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data as data
import dataset
import model

# Define hyperparameters
batch_size = 2
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 10

# Load the dataset
train_dataset = dataset.MaqamDataset(mode='train')

# Find the maximum length of the input tensors
max_length = 0
for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
    inputs, labels = train_dataset[i]
    if inputs.shape[0] > max_length:
        max_length = inputs.shape[0]

# Pad all input tensors to the maximum length
train_dataset.pad_to_max_length(1440000)
train_loader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# Define the model
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = model.MaqamCNN().to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Train the model
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data
        print(inputs.shape)
        inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(3)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        print("Outputs shape = ", outputs.shape)
        batch_size1 = outputs.size(0)
        padding_size = max_length - outputs.size(1)
        padding = torch.zeros(batch_size1, padding_size).to(device)
        padded_outputs = torch.cat((outputs, padding), dim=1)
        loss = criterion(padded_outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    print('Epoch %d, loss: %.3f' % (epoch + 1, running_loss / len(train_loader)))

# Save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'maqam_cnn.pth')
```

But every time in a different level in the training process jumps the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\omari\Documents\GitHub\Classifying_Maqams\model3\train.py", line 38, in <module>
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
  File "C:\Users\omari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\omari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\omari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "C:\Users\omari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 84, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "C:\Users\omari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 84, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "C:\Users\omari\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 56, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1439994] at entry 0 and [1440000] at entry 1
```

I've tried to pdd the tensors using F.pad as you can  see in the following code:

```
    def pad_to_max_length(self, max_length):
        for i in range(len(self)):
            padded_data = F.pad(self.data[i][0], (0, max_length - len(self.data[i][0])), 'constant', 0)
            self.data[i] = (padded_data, self.data[i][1])
```

But also still having the same problem, I tried also padding it with 0's, but always I got the error with the same number which says that one entry is 1440000 and the other one is with the size of 1439994!
any help, please?

edit:
The model code:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class MaqamCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MaqamCNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=(5, 1), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 0))
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(4, 1), stride=(4, 1))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=(5, 1), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 0))
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(4, 1), stride=(4, 1))
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*90000, 128)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 8)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        print(x.shape)
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        x = x.view(batch_size, -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.relu3(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        print("x shape = ", x.shape)
        return x
```

Comment: what model are you using?

Comment: How is your dataset?

Comment: My dataset is consisting of a Folder that have 8 folders inside, each one with the name of the label, in each folder of these there is a different audio sample that represents each label, each file with a different length and with type .wav for all, there is different number of samples in each folder, between 50-70 wav files in each folder, each file in length between 30-60 sec.
The model is CNN
I will edit the question so it will include also the model.